# Q: Arista, can you read spanning-tree status via SNMP

Tags: switch, snmp, spanning-tree

Is it possible to use SNMP to read the spanning-tree status from Arista switches?

Although it is possible to set up SNMP traps for spanning-tree, I did not find anything related to spanning-tree in the [Arista SNMP MIBs list](https://www.arista.com/en/support/product-documentation/arista-snmp-mibs), or any mention of the possibility of querying STP status via SNMP in the documentation.

We have several models, in case that is important (DCS-7050T, DCS-7050QX, DCS-7060CX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arista's BRIDGE-MIB implementation doesn't appear to have the `dot1dStp` subtree.

```
# snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.2
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.2 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

ETA:  Confirmed with Arista support.  Nor is the relevant YANG model implemented.  These are on the roadmap, but no timeline.

Answer (score 0):

[Arista supports](https://www.arista.com/en/support/product-documentation/arista-snmp-mibs) [RFC 4188: Definitions of Managed Objects for Bridges](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4188), which covers Spanning Tree Protocol (STP) under the `dot1dStp Group` ([OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.2](https://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.2.1.17.2)).

From there you can obtain information about such things as priority, designated root, topology changes, timers, etc.